# checking constrains in a ruby Hash

Tags: ruby

I have created a map and am fetching values for the keys from the database in the following way

```
def data
 myMaps.map do |Mymap|
 {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  kay3: value3
 }
end 
end
```

If I had to check if the value 1 is nil, what is the correct syntax?
I want to assign the key value pair only if the value is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should check out the documentation for #map [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map). Just from your question it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do. Your method would assume that `myMaps` was an array, and then map a hash onto each value, with three keys and three values. I'm not 100% sure, but I think what you want is something more like:

```
myMaps = { key2: value2, key3: value3 }
myMaps[key1] = value1 unless value1.nil?
```

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but I get stuck with this error ' unexpected kUNLESS_MOD'

Answer (score 0):

The way to assign a value to an Hash key when the value is nil is the following

```
hash[:key] ||= "value"
```

I'm not sure how to properly answer your question because it's quite unclear.

First of all there is no Map data type in Ruby. What you probably call Map is actually a Hash. However, there is not `map` method for `Hash`, just for [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) so I assume that `myMaps` is an `Array` but there is no evidence of where such variable is defined.

Comment: I am creating a hash where the values for the keys are fetched from the database. I want to assign the key value pair in the hash only if that value exists in the database (not nil) else skip that key value pair and proceed to the next one.